# Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer using Active Directory based user credentials

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

I am looking to transfer data and schema between Azure SQL database using the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer` and would like to use an Active Directory username and password. I am able to load the objects from both the source and destination databases using a connection string using

```
Authentication="Active Directory Password"
```

and the username and password but have no clue how to get the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer` object to connect to the destination server using AD credentials.

The following code returns an error when I try to pass it an Active Directory username and password:

```
Transfer transfer = new Transfer(sourceDatabase);
transfer.DestinationServer = destinationConnection.ServerInstance;
transfer.DestinationDatabase = destinationConnection.DatabaseName;
transfer.DestinationLogin = serverCredentials.UserName;
transfer.DestinationPassword = serverCredentials.Password;
transfer.DestinationLoginSecure = false;
var stuffToDo = transfer.ScriptTransfer();
```

**Note: I cannot use a native SQL Server login since they are not part of our current security design.**

To add some clarity, the database is already configured to use Active Directory authentication and the user name and password mentioned in the code block above are for a valid administrator account on the Azure SQL databases.  I can connect using a connection string with the AD accounts its just when I try to use the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer` object that things fail.

Comment: Azure SQL database(Paas) does not support local AD user login, you could use Azure AD user to login your sql database.

Comment: You could check this link  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure